# Is it possible to use 'and' in re.search?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I need to search multiple words in each line and if all the words are matching in a line then print that line.

file.txt

```
This is starting string.
This is starting but different string.
This is starting but the same string.
This is a differnet string.
This is a old string.
```

i have done in below manner.

```
import re
with open("file.txt", "r") as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        if (re.search('different',line)) and (re.search('string',line)):
            print line
```

But i need something like:

```
if (re.search('different' and 'string',line))::
            print line
```

I know we have or as we use

```
if (re.search('different'|'string',line))::
                print line
```

Can anybody help me to use 'and' in similar manner.

Comment: Why are you using regex at all? `all(w in line for w in ('different', 'string'))` would work just as well. Otherwise: no, there is no 'and' regex option.

Comment: And from the duplicate: `re.search(r'(?=.*different)(?=.*string)', line)` works for case too.

Comment: @martijn-pieters: Thankyou for just remembering the basics.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use module `re` in here, `in` operator will do the job for ya.

```
if 'different' in line and 'string' in line:
```

Comment: Thank you. I was having idea on this, that's why i tried the same in regex also and added to my post. Anyhow all(x in line for x in ['different', 'string']) has done complete job to me. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

In your case there is no need to use regexp, you can just do `'string' in line and 'different' in line`, or `all(x in line for x in ['different', 'string'])`

Comment: Thankyou very much. I could't add +1 but thankyou.